# Voltar para view anterior com dados preenchidos

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Tenho 3 View's, uma principal (Index) contendo campos para realizar filtros e um botão de pesquisa, outra ,GridIndex (renderizada dentro da view Index), onde são demonstrados os registros com base nos filtros de pesquisa, e uma terceira (Informacao) que é exibida quando o usuário clica em um botão existente na GridIndex.

Quando o usuario acessa a view de informações, e volta para página anterior, apenas a view Index é exibida, obrigando o usuário a clicar no botão pesquisar novamente para exibir os registros.

Existe uma maneira de, quando o usuário voltar para a pagina anterior, além da Index, exibir a GridIndex preenchida?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `GET` ao invés de `POST`:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Acao", "Controller", FormMethod.Get))
{
    ...
}
```

A *Action* que recebe o `POST` deve permitir `GET` também:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get | HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Index(ObjetoPesquisa objPesquisa) 
{
    ...
}
```

No `GET` os dados da sua pesquisa são preservados na URL, diferentemente do `POST`. Para funcionar no `POST`, seria necessário armazenar tudo em `Session`, o que não é recomendado.